# How to view the procedural code for any xaml file

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 with xaml to create an application. When I make a new solution and WPF project and look at the xaml in the application file, I see `xmlns`, a `startupuri`, and a tag for `application.resources`.

When I want to see the code-behind that these tags are creating, I have only the .cs file with maybe a few things in it and the mysterious `InitializeComponent()` that performs all of the parsing. Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window //This is generated with a wpf project.
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

If possible, how can I view the procedurally generated code that `InitializeComponent` is creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project directory, under the obj and Debug folders should be files labeled `.g.cs` that correspond to existing files. Presumably, these are *Generated C-Sharp files* that contain the generated code that I was looking for.

Comment: Should be there but aren't. The only code in App.xaml.g.cs is :
`private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(App));
}`
Most likely this is less than expected.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the complete xaml source gets compiled into .g.cs files.

Quoting [this](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/guidedtourwpf_1.aspx) codeproject article:

> When you compile a WPF application in Visual Studio it will compile your XAML files into a compressed representation known as Binary Application Markup Language (BAML). The BAML is then saved as a resource in the resultant assembly. When that assembly is loaded and the resource is requested, the BAML is streamed out and very quickly turned into the object graph described by the original XAML.